# group array of dictionaries by date from xml in iOS

Tags: ios, parsing

Here is my code. Please Help.

```
NSDictionary *xmlDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:Str];
NSArray *fixtureslist1 = [[xmlDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"eMatches"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryByDate = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in fixtureslist1)
{
    NSString *dateString = dictionary[@"MatchDate"];
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithSameDate = self.resultsSection[dateString];
    if(! arrayWithSameDate)
    {
        arrayWithSameDate = [NSMutableArray new];
        self.resultsSection[dateString] = arrayWithSameDate;
    }
    [arrayWithSameDate addObject: dictionary];
}
//NSLog(@"dictionaryByDate:%@",self.resultsSection);
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
reverseOrder=[[self.resultsSection allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
NSLog(@"results:%@",reverseOrder);
```

Comment: Hai any one pls help me aim stuck here from past 1 week

Comment: Please explain your problem. You have just pasted your code. Its not enough. Tell us what you will get in XML and how you are trying to group them.

Comment: aim getting the below response as array which contains inner dictionaries ,i want to group them according to date in descending order

Comment: I didn't see any response?

Comment: hi @user3614885! please update your question with the response code that you get. Also please mention your requirements in the question itself, rather than commenting it below.

Comment: http://api.qlao.com/mobileservice.svc//GetResultsListForUserFans/userid=83e1e30d-9d53-4aa3-9999-3b3d95beec24,parse data in this url as group by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *sections;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [self setupSections];

- (void)setupSections
{
    BOOL found;

    // Loop through the items and create our keys
    for (YourObject *item in self.items)
    {
        NSString *date= item.Matchdate;
        found = NO;
        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:date])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            [self.sections setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:date];
        }
    }
    // Loop again and sort the items into their respective keys
    for (YourObject *item in self.items)
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:item.MatchDate addObject:item];
    }

    for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“MatchDate" ascending:NO]]];
    }
//Reload tableView by using self.sections
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionHeader = @"";
    if(!isFiltered)
    {
        sectionHeader = [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    return sectionHeader;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int rowCount;
    rowCount = [[self.sections objectForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];

    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITAbleViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    YourObject *item = [[self.sections objectForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It crashes the application

Comment: Now i don't have enf time to cross verify the code.For time being plz reverse the self.items array.

Comment: @user3614885 Please stop asking for offline help for this issue.  People answer questions on Stack Overflow voluntarily and harassing them is not appropriate.

Comment: Iam asking help not harassing anybody,if u can help give answer or else keep quite

Comment: @user3614885 repeatedly asking users for their skype or facebook contact details is harassment.  Not only that, but questions should be answered on the site not elsewhere, otherwise it is not helpful to other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the xml response , and make array of dictionaries.Then you can sort by using following code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [arrayOfDictionaries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Hai i want to sort in descending order and display in grouped uitableview,i tried this but its not working

Comment: Edit your question with XML response and NSlog of arrayOfDictionaries(fixturesList1)

Comment: api.qlao.com/mobileservice.svc//GetResultsListForUserFans/83e1e30d-9d53-4aa3-9999-3b3d95beec24 check from this link

Comment: Hai can anyone pls help me

Comment: this link not working for me.Plz upload the response to ur question

Comment: HTScore = "[0-0]";
    IsUserXpectedCorrectly = false;
    LeagueId = 1086;
    LeagueName = "Australia- A-League";
    MatchDate = "2014-04-27T00:00:00";
    MatchFlag1 = "http://qlao.com/images/Flags/6157.jpg";
    MatchFlag2 = "http://qlao.com/images/Flags/6216.jpg";
    MatchId = 1732522;
    MatchStatusId = 1;
    MatchStatusName = "Full Time";
    MatchTime = "07:00";
    TeamAExtraTimeScore = 0;
    TeamAFinalScore = 1;
    TeamAId = 6157;
    TeamAName = "Brisbane Roar";
    TeamAPenaltyScore = 0;
    TeamAUserExpectedScore = 0;
    TeamBExtraTimeScore = 0;..........

Comment: Cool.change key @"date" to @"MatchDate", and check once

Comment: its ok but grouping only dates not all array which has dictionaries,i want to load in sectioned uitableview